# Clean up ugly WYSIWYG HTML code? Python or *nix utility

Tags: python, html, regex, django, wysiwyg

I'm finally upgrading (*rewriting* ;) ) my first Django app, but I am migrating all the content.

I foolishly gave users a full *WYSIWYG* editor for certain tasks, the HTML code produced is of course terribly ugly with more extra tags than content.

**Does anyone know of a library or external shell app I could use to clean up the code?**

I use tidy sometimes, but as far as I know that doesn't do what I'm asking. I want to simplify all the extra span and other garbage tags. I cleaned the most offensive offending styles with some regex, but I it would take a really long time to do anything more using just regex.

Any ideas?

Comment: The standard answer is `Beautiful Soup`.  "Extra span" and "garbage tags" is something you'll need to define very, very carefully so you can remove the tags without removing content.

Comment: It *might* be a better idea to redo the HTML rather than sanitise the one you have.

Answer (score 3):

You could also take a look at [Bleach](https://github.com/jsocol/bleach) a white-list based HTML sanitizer. It uses html5lib to do what Kyle posted, but you'll get a lot more control over which elements and attributes are allowed in the final output.

Answer (score 2):

Beautiful Soup will probably get you a more complete solution, but you might be able to get some cleanup done more simply with html5lib (if you're OK with html5 rules):

```
import html5lib
from html5lib import sanitizer, treebuilders, treewalkers, serializer

my_html = "<i>Some html fragment</I>" #intentional 'I'

html_parser = html5lib.HTMLParser(tree=treebuilders.getTreeBuilder("dom"))
dom_tree = html_parser.parseFragment(my_html)
walker = treewalkers.getTreeWalker("dom")
stream = walker(dom_tree)
s = serializer.htmlserializer.HTMLSerializer(omit_optional_tags=False, quote_attr_values=True)
cleaned_html = s.render(stream)
cleaned_html == '<i>Some html fragment</i>"
```

You can also sanitize the html by initializing your html_parser like this:

```
html_parser = html5lib.HTMLParser(tree=treebuilders.getTreeBuilder("dom"), tokenizer=sanitizer.HTMLSanitizer)
```

Answer (score 0):

The standard answer is `Beautiful Soup`.

"Extra span" and "garbage tags" is something you'll need to define very, very carefully so you can remove the tags without removing content.

I would suggest you do two things.

1. Fix  your app so that users don't provide HTML under any circumstances.  Django can use RST markup which is much more user-friendly.  http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/builtins/#django-contrib-markup
2. Write a Beautiful Soup parser and transform the user's *content* into RST markup.  Keep the structural elements (headings, lists, etc.) and lose the formatting to the extent possible.