# How to prevent BeautifulSoup from self-closing things that look like tags but aren't?

Tags: python, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

I'm using BeautifulSoup to escape all of the HTML tags (except for a set of pre-approved tags, like a) from an arbitrary set of text.  However, I only want it to escape the tags if they are actual valid HTML tags.  If something looks like a tag, but isn't, it ends up adding some HTML to close it off, which I don't want.

Example: If someone enters in the text `<integer>`, my code ends up spitting out `&lt;integer&gt;&lt;/integer&gt;` instead of just `&lt;integer&gt;`

Here's the code (`value` is the HTML string and `VALID_TAGS` is just a list of acceptable tag names).

```
soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(
  value, convertEntities=BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup.HTML_ENTITIES)
# Loop through all the tags. If it is invalid, escape the characters.
for tag in soup.findAll():
  if tag.name not in VALID_TAGS:
    tag.replaceWith(cgi.escape(str(tag)))
return soup.renderContents()
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: My opinion is that you're using the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: At the very least you should also be filtering the attributes; `<a onmouseover="alert('Oh dear')">Look at this!</a>` Take a look at http://html5sec.org.

Comment: I'm filtering the attributes out as well (except, again, for a whitelist).  I removed it from the example code and question for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured this out using html5lib based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6053062/1148843) as a starting point.  Here's a version of what I ended up with that does the same thing as the BeautifulSoup code I started with above, except works properly for the `<integer>` case I described:

```
p = html5lib.HTMLParser(tokenizer=sanitizer.HTMLSanitizer, tree=treebuilders.getTreeBuilder("dom"))
dom_tree = p.parseFragment(value)
walker = treewalkers.getTreeWalker("dom")
stream = walker(dom_tree)
s = serializer.htmlserializer.HTMLSerializer(quote_attr_values=True)
return s.render(stream)
```

Thanks to everyone who helped.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong (tm).
BeatifulSoup is not meant to be used like that.
Take a look at this instead: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/52281-strip-tags-and-javascript-from-html-page-leaving-o/
This recipe removes invalid tags and you sound like you want to keep them in but escaped.  Should be a pretty easy modification.

Comment: The problem here is that recipe uses sgmllib, which is deprecated after 2.6.

Comment: OK, so use HTMLParser like described here http://unethicalblogger.com/2008/05/03/parsing-html-with-python.html

Comment: Coded it up and it worked for most cases, but choked on invalid-looking input like `<<script>script>alert("Biscuit!");</</script>script`